# How to connect rasa chatbot to human live chat

Tags: python, rasa

I am new to rasa and rasa x . I have created one payload button to trigger live chat to human in rasa. But I have no idea how to use socket io to connect.

Comment: Rasa X is unfortunately not going to be supported for long anymore. See: https://rasa.com/rasa-x/. If you're building a new project I would recommend to build the project on a framework that's not in the end of support phase

Comment: @SteinnHauserMagnusson what OP is asking here is about handover to human agent (user) not about Rasa X. Rasa open source and Rasa X are considered separate software. The Rasa open source is still supported. So for setting up  handover functionality in rasa bot, you can follow this tutorial. It's quite comprehensive: https://rasa.com/blog/how-to-build-a-human-handoff-feature-with-rasa/

Comment: @OlasimboArigbabu Thank you for the information its quite helpful for me to stop bot to respond but I have one more query is how can I connect human to my rasa chatbot using socketio in python.